# whats the use of nodeType in this code?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function prev( node ){
    do {
       elem = elem.previousSibling;
    } while( elem && elem.nodeType != 1 );
return elem;
}
```

In this function we are looking for previous node to a given node. Got this piece of code from  John Resig work. This works perfectly I would like have deep understanding of this specifically **why he checks elem.nodeType != 1**

Somebody pls explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nodeType == 1` is an element node.

So this code selects first previous node that is an element.

Full list of node types you can [find here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

ITs checking whether its an element node (ELEMENT_NODE)

Ref: [Node Type](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml)